# what is the Probability of selecting 10 SNPs from a list of 5000 SNPs simply by chance

Tags: r, probability, binomial-distribution

We conducted a study to predict deleterious mutations from a list of around 5000 mutations (which contains both neutral and deleterious mutations; the real state of each mutation is unknown), using four publicly available SNP classifiers (prediction tools) e.g. Classifier_1, Classifier_2, Classifier_3 and Classifier_4.

Let's say, 
       Classifier_1 predicted 100 mutations as deleterious (i.e. remaining 4900 mutations as neutral) from the given 5000 mutations;  classifier_2 predicted 80 SNPs as deleterious (i.e. remaining 4920 mutations as neutral) from the given 5000 mutations; classifier_3 predicted 75 SNPs as deleterious (i.e. remaining 4925 mutations as neutral) from the given 5000 mutations, and classifier_4 predicted 95 SNPs as deleterious (i.e. remaining 4905 mutations as neutral) from the given 5000 mutations.

Then we calculated the prediction of deleterious SNPs from a combination of any two tools (e.g. deleterious SNPs from: classifier_1 & classifier_2), any three tools (e.g. deleterious SNPs from: classifier_1 & classifier_2 & classifier_3), and a combination of all four tools (e.g. deleterious SNPs from: classifier_1 & classifier_2 & classifier_3 & classifier_4). Predicted deleterious SNPs from these combinations are:

```
   classifier_1 = 100 deleterious SNPs,
   classifier_2 = 80 deleterious SNPs,
   classifier_3 = 75 deleterious SNPs,
   classifier_4 = 95 deleterious SNPs,
   classifier_1&2 = 44 deleterious SNPs,
   classifier_1&3 = 27 deleterious SNPs,
   classifier_1&4 = 32 deleterious SNPs,
   classifier_2&3 = 38 deleterious SNPs,
   classifier_2&4 = 32 deleterious SNPs,
   classifier_3&4 = 20 deleterious SNPs,
   classifier_1&2&3 = 18 deleterious SNPs,
   classifier_1&2&4 = 17 deleterious SNPs,
   classifier_1&3&4 = 11 deleterious SNPs,
   classifier_2&3&4 = 13 deleterious SNPs,
   classifier_1&2&3&4 = 10 deleterious SNPs.
```

Under this scenario, we want to calculate the probability of selecting these deleterious SNPs, in each level of prioritization (i.e. using one tool, a combination of two tools, a combination of three tools, and a combination of all four tools), simply by chance.

This analysis will assist us in inferring whether our prioritization scheme (i.e. application of one prediction tool, a combination of two tools, a combination of three tools, and a combination of all four tools) is effective or not.

We tried pbinom(x, n, p) and binom.test(x, n, p) where x = number of predicted deleterious SNPs e.g. 100 SNPs by classifier_1, n = total number of SNPs considered e.g. 5000, and p = 0.5 (i.e. random guessing); but not sure whether it is correct or not, and how to address all the situations.

> ##Example:

```
 Classifier_1 = binom.test(c(100, 4900), p = 0.5)
   Classifier_1     
   Exact binomial test

   data:  c(100, 4900)
   number of successes = 100, number of trials = 5000, p-value < 2.2e-16
   alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is not equal to 0.5
   95 percent confidence interval:
     0.01630168 0.02427257
   sample estimates:
   probability of success 
         0.02 

  Classifier_1 = pbinom(100, 5000, p = 0.5)
  Classifier_1
  [1] 0
```

I will really appreciate, if you guide me - how to calculate the probability of selecting these SNPs (from each tools, and a combination of all) simply by chance (i.e. prediction scheme is not effective).

Thank you all for your kind help .

Comment: This isn't answerable in the abstract. You will have to provide a lot more information before we can say anything of value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure of understanding this question. Here is what I understand.

You want a probability for each level of prioritization (one tool, any two tools, any three tools and the four tools).

for level 1 (any tool).
If we select a random SNP, the probability of it being a deleterious one is given by the following:

$$ P(x) = P \big(x\in (Classifier\_1 \cup Classifier\_2 \cup Classifier\_3 \cup Classifier\_4)\big) $$

which is the probability of a random SNP being classified as deleterious by any of the four tools.

Am I in the right path??

if so, check the [prob](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/prob/vignettes/prob.pdf) package of R, you could define a probability space and then use something like `Prob( union (union( union(T1,T2), T3), T4) )`.

Comment: You can create a probability space using the prob package, then you could compute the desired probabilities. If you need any help don't hesitate asking.